# How can I send an javascript object/array as key-value pairs via an AJAX post with easyXDM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

Recently I realized that I needed to use [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM) instead of jQuery's `$.ajax` in order to make a cross domain post request. After getting easyXDM set up I see that the functions line up fairly closely:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/",
    method: "POST",
    data: myData
});
```

easyXDM:

```
xhr.request({
    url: "/ajax/",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', // I added this trying to fix the problem, didn't work
    data: myData
});
```

myData is setup something like:

```
myData = {};
myData[1] = 'hello';
myData[2] = 'goodbye';
myData[3] = {};
myData[3][1] = 'sub1';
myData[3][2] = 'sub2';
myData[3][3] = 'sub3';
```

When I make the request with jQuery it handles the sub fields properly, but not with easyXDM.

Here is how the POST request comes into the server with jQuery:

[screenshot-with-shadow.png http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png)

And here is how it comes in with easyXDM:

[screenshot-with-shadow.png http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/4526/screenshotwithshadow.png)

How can I send an javascript object/array of key-value pairs via an easyXDM / XHR request like jQuery does?

Comment: From the docs: "If not set easyXDM will try to use the native JSON object", so unless you are overriding the serializer then your object should come out as you expect? Perhaps type coercion is happening somewhere in your preceding code?

Comment: Looks like this might be an issue with easyXDM. Looks like in the cors/index.html file it will try and serialize the data without first checking to see if it is already a string and it doesn't seem to handle multi-level JSON encoding... https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/issues/199

Comment: @robC - regarding your now deleted comment I think it is an issue with easyXDM - see my test http://pastebin.com/0eusK2vr

Comment: @cwd Agree that does seem to be the problem. Apologies for muddying the water, looking at the src I am suprised to see that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of the limitations of easyXDM discussed in the comments, the only way you can use it would be to serialize your data manually when passing it to .request i.e.

```
xhr.request({
    url: "/ajax/",
    method: "POST",
    data: {jsonData: JSON.stringify(myData)}
});
```

Alternatively you could create your own postMessage solution but you will be excluding IE7 and below.

Comment: This looks like a clever workaround until that issue is hopefully resolved. I will give it a try.

Comment: very clever indeed! easiest solution, at least for now! thanks! :)

Comment: @SteveBrown don't forget to include a JSON implementation for IE7! https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: thanks. easyXDM actually takes care of adding JSON support if it doesn't already exist :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken about sending a request cross-domain via AJAX. You CAN indeed send a request cross-domain via AJAX regardless of the JavaScript API. However, in order to receive a response cross-domain, the response needs to be of data type [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

JSONP is simply JSON with padding, for example:

**JSON:**

```
{ Key: "Hello", Value: "World" }
```

**JSONP:**

```
callback({ Key: "Hello", Value: "World" })
```

It is a subtle difference but JSONP by-passes browser same-origin policy and allows you to consume JSON data served by another server.

To consume JSON data coming from another server via jQuery AJAX try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.com/Service.svc/GetJSONP?callback=callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: myData,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

For this to work you must make sure that your web service is returning results as JSONP and not JSON.

Comment: easyXDM uses a hidden iframe with postMessage, not jsonp!

Comment: I am trying to use easyXDM because jQuery's cross domain ajax requests are not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @SteveBrown JSONP will work in all browsers. But you can't use POST it has to be a GET request.

Comment: iframe's in general are bad news. Any web service returning JSON data which is intended to be consumed cross-domain should serve this data as JSONP. It is a simple and elegant solution using jQuery to consume this data and I highly recommend you implement this strategy rather than using easyXDM and an iframe to send your request and consume the response.

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells - you're not exactly helping answer my question. I want to do a POST request and I want it to work in all browsers. I don't agree with you on `iframe's in general are bad news`

Comment: The advantage of postMessage is that you can use POST and that you have the added security of verifying the request domain.

Comment: You can most certainly verify the requesting domain when using a GET request as well. In the HTTP header of the request there is a key 'Referer' which will tell you the requesting domain. I apologize for overlooking that you wanted to do this only as a POST, however, is there some other reason why you must use a POST request rather than using a GET?

Comment: @Christopher.Cubells - the data being sent is not going to be a fixed size and may be longer than the maximum allowed URL length.

Answer (score 1):

As easyXDM can't serialize properly you need to serialize data manually:

```
JSON.stringify(myData)
```

Since the request will now contain a json string rather than object then Index.html should not parse the properties to create json structure. Go to index.html that comes with easyXDM and locate the following code:

```
var pairs = [];
for (var key in config.data) {
    if (config.data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(config.data[key]));
    }
}
data = pairs.join("&");
```

Don't execute this code in a case of POST request. Just assign config.data to data:

```
data = config.data;
```